# Detecting empty string when decoding byte array into unicode? (Python)

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to read an array of bytes character by character and decode it to a unicode string, as below:

```
current_character = byte_array[0:1].decode("utf-8")
```

For each character, I'm trying to check whether the result of .decode("utf-8") equals the empty string, but I can't seem to be able to detect this. When I print out the result of decoding, I get the empty string. But how do I translate this detection into code?

I've tried:

```
if not current_character

if current_character is u""
```

But they both don't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: How about `current_character = byte_array.decode("utf-8")[0:1]`?

Comment: What do you mean by they don't work? Also, can you add a sample value for `byte_array`?

Comment: unrelated: utf-8 is a variable-length encoding: it is incorrect to decode a single byte at a time if arbitrary utf-8 encoded input is allowed.

Answer (score 5):

Binary strings seem to be written like `b'some data'`, so try this:

```py
if current_character == b'':
    # Code
```

Answer (score 1):

`if not current_character:` is the correct way to find out whether `current_character` is an empty string in Python. It is equivalent to `if len(current_character) == 0:`

```
>>> not ''
True
>>> not b''
True
```

If it doesn't work for you then something else is broken in your code.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if current_character == '':
    print('empty string')
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to decode one byte, just check if it equals 0

```
current_character = byte_array[x:x+1]
if current_character == 0x00:
    pass #...
```